# Kafka Consumer 0.8.2.0 Poll Error

Tags: apache-kafka

Is this intentioal in the Kafka 0.8.2.0 version, org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer, the method:

```
public Map<String, ConsumerRecords<K, V>> poll(long timeout) {
    return null;
}
```

Which version of 0.8.x.x should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the method above and many such methods aren't just implemented with the 0.8-x.x version of Kafka and they are available only since 0.9.0.0 versions! So this means that I should use the following:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

as a reference on how to write a kafka consumer!